# Cannot connect to my raspberry pi anymore

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I wanted to use my android phone as a display for my Raspberry Pi 4B, so I searched the internet, found an instruction and copied the code into my Pi, I was connected to (via SSH). This is the code I put into `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.42.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.42.0
broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

This sets the IP to a static one (`192.168.42.42`).
I rebooted and tried to SSH with IP `192.168.42.42`, because I thought, this was the new IP for the Raspberry Pi.
Long story short, it doesn't work. I also tried some other IP's, I cant find the IP in NUTTY or with nmap.
How can I connect to my PI now? (I don't have a monitor or a crossover LAN cable)

I'm using an older MacBook Pro with Linux Mint 19

*Where I got the code from: https://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/*

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [raspberrypi.se], [unix.se], or [su]. When you do, you should explain what happens when you run ssh, instead of just saying it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the SD card out of the Pi and put it in your Mac/Linux machine and correct/remove the `/etc/network/interfaces` file from the SD card.

Or, you could go to the SD card's `/boot` partition and `touch ssh` in that directory so that `sshd` starts and also create in that same directory a `wpa_supplicant` file to match a temporary WiFi hotspot you create on your phone or Mac. Then you can `ssh` into it over WiFi and whatever you want.

Comment: OMG Why didnt I think of that (facepalm) Thanks!